# Pull a field from an Access file that is in a Document Library

Tags: 2013, document-library, microsoft-access

When an access file is checked into a document library, I need to open it and get an ID field from one of the table and store the ID in the list. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way to do this. Couple of options

1. For bulk updating - you can create powershell script which iterates through the access files and updating the list field
2. You can create an event receiver on the document library and read the access file and dynamically update the list field

**Update**

In case of event receiver you can use `SPItemEventProperties` to get hold of the file object.

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
 {
         try
         {
             string szHttpUrl = properties.WebUrl + "/" + properties.AfterUrl;
             SPWeb openedWeb = properties.Web.Site.OpenWeb(properties.Web.ID);
             SPFile spf = openedWeb.GetFile(szHttpUrl);

             StreamReader file = new StreamReader(spfile.OpenBinaryStream());

             //use the stream to read etc.
         }
         catch (System.Exception exception)
         {
             //LOG ERROR
         }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response... We are going the event receiver route. Is there a way to open the access file in a stream in the event receiver?  Thanks again..

Comment: @PaulBaker I have updated my answer based on your comment